# How I can add a changelog in deb with CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, deb, cpack

I am building a debian package with CMAKE and CPACK. Everything is smooth with the build except that I can't find how to add a changelog file in the deb package. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What is the format of your changelog ? How is it generated ?

Comment: Until now I was using dh to generate the changelog file and before every release I was adding the changes manually and then I was building the package with dpkg-buildpackage

Comment: I don't understand the difference with adding a simple text file.

Comment: The changelog will be used by Debian archive. Check more info here: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#debian-changes-files-changes So I need a to add explicitily this information somewhere in CPACK but I cant find where.

Comment: Have you tried the approach shown here: [CPack_Debian](https://code.cor-lab.org/svn/cca/trunk/cca/cpack/CPackDebianConfig.cmake) and here all others files [CMake_Debian](https://code.cor-lab.org/svn/cca/trunk/cca/cpack/)  ?

Answer (score 3):

Since at least CMake 3, the Debian CPack generator provides the variable CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA, which is a list of arbitrary files to add to the control section of the package.

You can write/generate your changelog file, and add it to this variable:

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/changelog")
```

See the CMake [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html) for more.

===== EDIT =====

Lintian (quite rightly) [doesn't like](http://people.ubuntuwire.org/%7Ebroder/lintian/saucy/tags/changelog-file-missing-in-native-package.html) the above solution.  The changelog should be compressed and installed in `/usr/share/doc/package-name/changelog.gz`.  The following code works on Linux:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changelog.gz"
    COMMAND gzip -cn9 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/changelog" > "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changelog.gz"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/changelog"
    COMMENT "Compressing changelog"
)

add_custom_target(changelog ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changelog.gz")

install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changelog.gz"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR}"
)
```

`add_custom_command` adds a hook to re-generate changelog.gz when its dependencies (changelog) change. `add_custom_target` adds a target to generate changelog.gz at build time. `install` installs the compressed changelog to the correct location.

The code should go in a CMakeLists.txt file in the same directory as the changelog. Unfortunately, CMake doesn't seem to have a cross-platform way to compress single files yet.

Comment: It works for me. What's going wrong? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: `lintian` doesn't accept this solution, moreover according to Debian guidelines changelog should be compressed using `gzip -9`

Comment: [This](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-docs.html#s-changelogs) only says they should be **installed** compressed, so I question your conclusion here.  As for `lintian` not accepting the solution, what's the error?  This solution is transparent enough that it should be clear why it fails.

Comment: @pktiuk I've updated my answer. Hope this helps - I don't get any warnings or errors from lintian now.

Comment: The command that works for me is: `gzip -ck9 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/changelog" > "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changelog.gz"`

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for pointing out my typos. Fixed now. I can't see a -k option in the gzip docs (https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) so I haven't changed that bit.

Comment: Hm... I suppose that man is outdated. Probably in 2012 they added more options.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gzip.1.html

                  If I don't specify `-k`, the original `changelog` is deleted from source directory.

Comment: Interesting. -c should imply -k (I have verified this on Debian 10).

Comment: Thank you for your workaround. I filed an issue at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24929 giving a slightly improved variant of it.